# What is the folder for Sony Xperia P

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I build a aplication supputing all the diferent sizes of screans (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi). The problem is that when I run my application on the Sony Xperia P (Sony Xperia LT22i 540 x 960 pixel - 4") the layout satay a mess. In what folder do I have to put the layout from  to this device? And how to prevent to happen this mess againg with another device?

**UPDATE**

I did diferents layouts xml for diferents folders.

Comment: You only made bigger images to support bigger screens ?
You should also make different layouts. For example, for a screen size of 4-7" make a layout-large folder, copy your "normal" xml files into it and modify them to scale bigger screens. This link should help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I did this. I did diferents layouts xml for diferents folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about [Using LinearLayout](http://logc.at/2011/10/18/when-to-use-linearlayout-vs-relativelayout/)

If you use LinearLayout correctly you can have even **one** Layout that can fit **ALL** screen sizes..

Comment: Using linear layout ins the best way to build an android app. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create a folder with layout-(**small|normal|large|xlarge**) and put your XML layout here.

**ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi** refer to the images not for layouts.

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more info.

In your case, you could create a `layout-w540dp-h960dp` folder.

> Available screen width    wdp
>
> Examples: w720dp w1024dp
>
> Specifies a minimum available width in dp
>   units at which the resources should be used—defined by the  value.
>   The system's corresponding value for the width changes when the
>   screen's orientation switches between landscape and portrait to
>   reflect the current actual width that's available for your UI.
>
> This is often useful to determine whether to use a multi-pane layout,
>   because even on a tablet device, you often won't want the same
>   multi-pane layout for portrait orientation as you do for landscape.
>   Thus, you can use this to specify the minimum width required for the
>   layout, instead of using both the screen size and orientation
>   qualifiers together.

and

> Available screen height   hdp
>
> Examples: h720dp h1024dp etc.
>
> Specifies a minimum screen height in dp
>   units at which the resources should be used—defined by the  value.
>   The system's corresponding value for the height changes when the
>   screen's orientation switches between landscape and portrait to
>   reflect the current actual height that's available for your UI.
>
> Using this to define the height required by your layout is useful in
>   the same way as wdp is for defining the required width, instead of
>   using both the screen size and orientation qualifiers. However, most
>   apps won't need this qualifier, considering that UIs often scroll
>   vertically and are thus more flexible with how much height is
>   available, whereas the width is more rigid.

Comment: I did this folder "layout-w540dp-h960dp". When I try to open this layout in the editor. It opens the editor for a tablet.

Comment: or try layout-w960dp-h540dp i don't remember which comes first (WxH or HxW)

Comment: Its the "layout-w540dp-h960dp". If I do "layout-w960dp-h540dp" it give me a error. But I remain not get to open in the right editor.